Sort xml segment by certain field if present
I need an xls version 1 to sort ascending some segments of my document if they contain a value.
<root><!-- some content to not touch --><segment><!-- segment not containing the "field" by which to sort --></segment><segment><field>1</field><!-- some fields to not touch --></segment><segment><field>3</field><!-- some fields to not touch --></segment><segment><field>2</field><!-- some fields to not touch --></segment><segment><!-- segment not containing the "field" by which to sort --></segment></root>

Expected Output
<root><!-- some content to not touch --><segment><!-- segment not containing the "field" by which to sort --></segment><segment><field>1</field><!-- some fields to not touch --></segment><segment><field>2</field><!-- some fields to not touch --></segment><segment><field>3</field><!-- some fields to not touch --></segment><segment><!-- segment not containing the "field" by which to sort --></segment></root>

I'm trying with this xsl but it is not working:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template><xsl:template match="*"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="segment"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="segment"><xsl:sort select="@field" data-type="number" order="ascending"/></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:copy></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:template><xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Are all the segments that need to be sorted always in a contiguous block? If not, should each block be sorted separately, or ... ? Also, are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

They should always be contguous.

Please answer both questions.

I'm not sure versions other than 1.0 are supported by my platform.

What is the platform? XSLT 3 with Saxon is available for Java, .NET, JavaScript/Node.js, Python 3, PHP 8, C++, though of course for e.g. Python or Java you need to be able to install the Saxon library/package.

Here is one way you could look at it:
XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="segment[field][1]/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="segment[field]">
            <xsl:sort select="field"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="segment[field][last()]/following-sibling::node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

As noted in the comments, this assumes all the segment elements  that have a field are in a single contiguous block, optionally preceded and/or followed by other nodes.

Added:

how to handle non-contiguous elements? In this case, sorting each block separately?
i can use v.2.0

You could do:
XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="segment" group-adjacent="boolean(field)">   
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:sort select="field"/>
                    </xsl:perform-sort> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/> 
                </xsl:otherwise>  
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Could you please let me know how to handle non-contiguous elements? In this case, sorting each block separately?

That's considerably more difficult in XSLT 1.0. Are you sure you cannot use XSLT 2.0 or higher?

Ok, I just saw i can use v.2.0

See the addition to my answer.
